# Create 2 Primary Key using EF Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I follow tutorial from this https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/implementing-entity-framework-with-mvc-8931?l=mBKHDFC3_9204984382. This is my code

```
namespace FluentAPI
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new MusicContext())
        {
            var album = new Album() { Price = 9.95m, Title = "YUhuu" };
            context.Albums.Add(album);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public class Album
    {
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class MusicContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("MusicStore");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Album>().HasKey(t => t.AlbumId);

            //tell EF to map string into varchar
            modelBuilder.Entity<Album>().Property(t => t.Title).IsUnicode(false);

            //Album id not going to be identity
            modelBuilder.Entity<Album>()
                .Property(t => t.AlbumId)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

It suppose to create a table in database, with `AlbumId` as a primary key. But when I run this program, the table result is not what i expected. There are 2 Primary Key : `AlbumId` and `Title`. I just want `AlbumId` as my primary key. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: can you show the table structure (SQL)?

Comment: Are you connecting to an existing database or you create the database from your code? Because the code looks good.

Comment: @syned I create the database from code

Answer (score 0):

`[Key]` annotation is missing on top of `AlbumId`.

Comment: That's not needed, since the EF code-first **convention** comes into play, which makes `Id` or `(entity)Id` the **key** by default .... plus there's this line in the code: `modelBuilder.Entity<Album>().HasKey(t => t.AlbumId);` which also sets `AlbumId` to be the key .